# Suggest online sites/forums to get technical support with Xenobiology

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, xenobiology

Those who have read my recent questions posted here will have noticed that my questions are often related to hardcore biochemistry, atmospheric processes etc. While I have had some good answers to parts of these I would like to solicit suggestions as to what other Q+A sites and/or forums might be better equipped to handle the highly technical and scientific aspects of my xenobiology queries.

My generally weak areas of knowledge tend to be in biology/biochemstry, geology and astronomy. I find that the answers on this site relating to astronomy/planetology/geology are pretty high quality and sufficient for my worldbuilding needs but I think I need somewhere more specialist for the xenobiology questions.

Can anyone recommend where to take questions about the metabolic capabilities of dimethylsulfonium proprionate, for example? It would need to be a site that is comfortable with fielding questions about hypothetical xenobiology from non-practitioners (e.g. non academics). I realise there are other stack exchanges that might fit the bill but want to take input from those that have used them or other resources.

Comment: I think this is perfectly on-topic if we look at it as a resource request.  The answer should probably also be applied to the tag wiki.

Comment: @James It's not clear if it's on-topic, probably  : http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/do-we-want-resource-recommendation-questions/2555#2555

Comment: I did wonder if people would regard it as on topic. I feel that it is, because its about worldbuilding resources. It is not a question purely about biochemsitry.

Answer (score 1):

Best resource I know of (contains lots of useful related other stuff too) is actually a book called **[Xenology](http://www.xenology.info/Xeno.htm)**, by Robert A. Freitas Jr. It has been posted online in full by the author. A little bit is dated, but a very thorough walkthrough regardless.

Look to
Chapter 6.  A Definition of Life,
Chapter 7.  The Origin of Life,
Chapter 8.  Exotic Biochemistries,
Chapter 10.  Alien Bioenergetics.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Xenobiology.info was my best option too.  I couldn't find a forum for it though.

Answer (score 0):

Another resource is [Speculative Evolution](http://speculativeevolution.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page). It's a website where a bunch of people collected resources for Xenology over the past few years.